# Convert SQL Server 2012 CTE to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have the below query which works fine in 2012 as it is using the 2012 features. Can anyone make the exact same query work in 2008 with same output? I am looking to get Bucket filling data from Filler table to Bucket table. I get error when executing it in SQL 2008.`The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled`

```
declare @Buckets table (ID char(2), FullCapacity int)
declare @Filler table (ID char(2), Filler int)

insert into @Buckets values
('B1', 100),
('B2', 50),
('B3', 70)

insert into @Filler values
('F1', 90),
('F2', 70),
('F3', 40),
('F4', 20)

;with fillerCte as
(
select 
ID,
Filler,
sum(Filler) over (order by ID) as TotalFill
from @Filler
), 
BucketCte as
(
select 
ID,
FullCapacity,
sum(FullCapacity) over (order by ID) - FullCapacity as RunningTotalCapacity
from @Buckets
)
select 
b.ID, 
b.FullCapacity,
case 
when f.TotalFill < b.RunningTotalCapacity then 0
when f.TotalFill > b.RunningTotalCapacity + b.FullCapacity then b.FullCapacity
else f.TotalFill - b.RunningTotalCapacity
end as CurrentAmount
from fillerCte as f
cross join BucketCte as b
order by f.ID, b.ID
```

Output table should have below showing filling process.

```
ID | FullCapacity | CurrentAmount       
---+--------------+--------------
B1 |    100       |    90        
B2 |     50       |     0    
B3 |     70       |     0
---+--------------+--------------
B1 |    100       |   100        
B2 |     50       |    50
B3 |     70       |    10
---+--------------+--------------
B1 |    100       |   100      
B2 |     50       |    50    
B3 |     70       |    50
---+--------------+--------------
B1 |    100       |   100        
B2 |     50       |    50    
B3 |     70       |    70
```

Comment: I get error below when executing it in SQL 2008.The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.

Comment: The only thing I can see that is not supported in the 2008 version is the running total. Here in SO, you can find plenty of examples of how to implement a running total in SQL Server without using a window function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information - it will be clearer than posting comments.

Comment: It's a known parser bug isn't it? don't you just need to drop the (order by ID)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the same query in SQL Server 2008, you have to calculate the running total in two steps, the first step is to rank the rows using the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)`, then use the row number to calculate the running total:

```
;WITH fillerCte as
(
  SELECT 
   ID,
   Filler,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RN
   FROM @Filler
), FillerRT
AS
(
  SELECT 
    f1.ID,
    f1.Filler,
    SUM(f2.Filler) AS TotalFill
  FROM fillerCte AS f1
  INNER JOIN fillerCte AS f2 ON f2.rn <= f1.rn
  GROUP BY f1.ID, f1.Filler
), BucketCte as
(
  SELECT
    ID,
    FullCapacity,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RN
  FROM @Buckets
),BucketRN
AS
(
  SELECT 
    b1.ID,
    b1.FullCapacity,
    SUM(b2.FullCapacity) - b1.FullCapacity AS RunningTotalCapacity
  FROM BucketCte AS b1 INNER JOIN BucketCte AS b2 ON b2.RN <= b1.RN
  GROUP BY b1.ID, b1.FullCapacity
)
select 
b.ID, 
b.FullCapacity,
case 
when f.TotalFill < b.RunningTotalCapacity then 0
when f.TotalFill > b.RunningTotalCapacity + b.FullCapacity then b.FullCapacity
else f.TotalFill - b.RunningTotalCapacity
end as CurrentAmount
from FillerRT as f
cross join BucketRN as b
order by f.ID, b.ID;
```

This will give you the same exact output of your query.

Comment: Thanks. it works. just a correction. replace 
   "sum(Filler) over (order by ID) as TotalFill" as  Filler as TotalFill

Comment: @user2123852 - Sorry, I forgot to remove it, try my edit again, it will work fine.